# Prevent react-router from load routes before redux is loaded

Tags: reactjs, redux, react-router

I have a pretty simple setup with my app looking like:

```
<Provider store={store}>
  <BrowserRouter>
    <App/>
  </BrowserRouter>
</Provider>
```

And a router switch like

```
  <Switch>
    <Route path={'/test'} component={comp1}/>
    <Route exact path={'/'} component={comp2}/>
  </Switch>
```

I haven't worked with routes much but I want to prevent those two routes from loading before my redux fetch is finished but I can't seem to get it working. I've tried checking if the data is loaded in redux, basically wrapping the switch with a check of

```
this.props.data.size > 0
```

but it seems to render anyway. They both use the same data so it seems like bad practice to fetch data into redux individually in both components when I should be able to just fetch once regardless of which route was loaded.

Comment: Can you clarify why `wrapping the switch with a check` doesn't work?

Comment: Andddd I'm an idiot and forgot I changed the return data from an object to an array so size would never work. Changing the check to length fixed it.

Comment: Ye,. The only thing I'd do is - to wrap it into additional component, and wrap `switch` into the wrapper. But general idea direction seems to be ok.

Comment: So you're thinking wrap the routes with a wrapper component containing the switch?

Answer (score 0):

Your general idea `checking if the data is loaded in redux` seems to be ok, the only thing I'd suggest you is to encapsulate this logic into a wrapper component:

```
export const CheckLoadedApp = (props) => this.props.data.lenght ? <App /> : 'Loading...';
```

And change your codebase accordingly:

```
<Provider store={store}>
  <BrowserRouter>
    <CheckLoadedApp />
  </BrowserRouter>
</Provider>
```

But, up to you :)

Comment: Ah gotcha. I do like this idea in order to de couple that logic from the router.